# How to control the author’s point of view in natural language generation models?

Tags: image-processing, nlp, linguistics, seq2seq, nlg

I am new to Natural Language Generation and I am currently in the experimentation phase. The motivating use-case is to generate one-sentence captions for images, but my question/problem is not unique to my current NLG use-case alone.

The first model I tried used a combination of a CNN and an RNN. Everything worked more or less as expected except the image caption sentences generated were sometimes written in the first person voice, sometimes in the second person voice, and other times in the third person voice.

For my image captioning use case I would like all of my photo captions to be written in the **second person voice**. I have searched google, google scholar, stack exchange, GitHub, etc with every keyword combination I can think of and I have come up with nothing on this topic.

**Are their any NLG techniques which will allow me to control the author’s point of view in the generated output?**

If not, the only path I can think of would be to build a training corpus which only includes sentences written in the second person point of view; but it seems like it would be difficult to build a corpus of sufficient size.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you train a separate network only for normalisation. I'm not sure if there is a dataset for your specific task. However, I believe by creating a rather small dataset and fine-tuning bert to receive a sequence with different points of views and generate the second person voice version of it you can achieve satisfactory results and save some time.

Answer (score 0):

Rule-based NLG systems such as [SimpleNLG](https://github.com/simplenlg) allow you to change the person and tense of a phrase.  The problem you face is that your corpus contains free text descriptions, not descriptions defined by such a formal grammar.

Whilst it might be possible to convert your descriptions to such a grammar it is perhaps overkill in your case.  If your descriptions are relatively simple you could try running them through a parser like [spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features).  This would identify the person (and tense) of pronouns in your descriptions.  You might just be able to change them ("I" to "you", "my" to "your" etc).  Alternatively, you could reject those which are not in the second person and train on a subset of the corpus.

Python Code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'A photo of you beside your car')

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
          token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop, nlp.vocab.morphology.tag_map[token.tag_])
```

Gives the output:

```
A a DET DT det X True False {74: 89}
photo photo NOUN NN ROOT xxxx True False {74: 91, 'Number': 'sing'}
of of ADP IN prep xx True True {74: 84}
you -PRON- PRON PRP pobj xxx True True {74: 94, 'PronType': 'prs'}
beside beside ADP IN prep xxxx True True {74: 84}
your -PRON- ADJ PRP$ poss xxxx True True {74: 83, 'PronType': 'prs', 'Poss': 'yes'}
car car NOUN NN pobj xxx True False {74: 91, 'Number': 'sing'}
```

You could write some simple morphology rules to change your descriptions, replacing every first and third person pronoun with the appropriate second person equivalent.  Take a look at SimpleNLG [MorphologyRules](https://github.com/simplenlg/simplenlg/blob/master/src/main/java/simplenlg/morphology/english/MorphologyRules.java) for some ideas.  This could lead to some mistakes in the corpus if there are cases where simple pronoun replacement is not enough, but without seeing some examples of your corpus it is difficult to comment further.